# How to get values from json reponse in laravel

Tags: json, laravel-5

Developing with laravel 5.4.

In the web file I have this route:

Route::get('cart/calcShipping/{shipping_method}', 'CartController@calcShipping');

I have a view with ajax call like this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            headers: { 'X-XSRF-TOKEN' : $_token },
            url: '{{ url("cart/calcShipping") }}' + '/1',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#shippingCost').val(data);
                $('#shippingCostText').text(data);
            }
        });
```

In my controller I have this function (I do some calculations that I did not include in the example. For testing I'm sending back hard coded values):

```
 public function calcShipping($shipping_method)
{
   return response()->json(['shipping_cost' => 100, 'order_total' => 200]);
}
```

The problem is I get [object Object] back on these lines, instead of the values:

```
$('#shippingCost').val(data);
$('#shippingCostText').text(data);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, duh, I have this call in two places, and in one of them I was only calling data.... pffff....